# nodeJs node-schedule not working properly

Tags: node.js, scheduler

I am using node-schedule package to schedule my job. I want to restart my server at specific hours in a day and below is the code:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

    /**
     * This is used to restart the server after some interval
     * we are using pm2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to run server as process
     * when the server is closed, pm2 automatically restart the server
     */
    var restartInterval='* 4,8,12,16,20,23 * * *';
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(restartInterval, function () {
        console.log("stopping server!!!!!");
        //Code to stop server
        try {
            process.exit(1);
        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

But the scheduler is not behaving properly, when i saw log at morning I notice that the job is executing at every minute. I have used [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/%22pm2%22) to auto-start server when it is stopped by scheduler.

am I missing something?

Comment: Hello, so right now you're stopping the server every minute?

Comment: yes, thats what happening right now.

Comment: Do you maybe have another scheduler elsewhere in your code with that frequency?

Comment: i dont have any other schedular in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I feel is the issue: 
Your `var restartInterval='* 4,8,12,16,20,23 * * *';` is actually going to execute the job every minute of the given hours, so once for example it's 12 o'clock, your server will be shut at 12:00, restarted, shut again at 12:01, and so on...

My guess is your log only shows minute-by-minute stop-restarts in the given hours.

If you want to be hour specific, use the following syntax:

```
var restartInterval='00 4,8,12,16,20,23 * * *';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use a simpler format of specifying the schedule, for example instead of cron expression you can use below convention which is more manageable:

/* This runs at 2:30AM on every Sunday */

```
cron.scheduleJob(**{hour: 2, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}**, function(){
    console.log('This runs at 2:30AM on every Sunday');
});
```

Also there are other modules out there for scheduling, in case you have a niche use case.

This is available under MIT licence.

https://github.com/agenda/agenda

Comment: this works if we want to run task at particular time but does not work if we want to execute task at continuous interval.